# Implementing a big collection entity without loading data into memory

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm implementing an entity **UserImages** with methods like **addImage**(*$imageId*), **removeImage**(*$imageId*), **getImages**(*$from, $count*).

Phisycally, the data (a collection of image ids) stored in an application-level storage, which provides nice functionality like **addItem**(*$keyName, $item, $weight*), **removeItem**(*$keyName, $item*), **getItems** (*$key, $from, $count*).

How to make model use this external (looking form the domain) storage in DDD-style, without referencing the storage from the **UserImages** entity? Important that I don't want to load all the collection from the storage to the entity, as a traditional approach suppose.

Hope I provided a good explanation of the problem, please do let me know if not. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`UserImages` does not sound like an **entity**, but more like a **service** or **repository**, which you already have an implementation for - the application-level storage. You may wish to expose this as a `UserImageRepository`, a **repository** being a more fitting name for what you have. More generally, whenever you have an association one end of which may have very large cardinality, consider [implementing this association as a repository](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/07/24/implementing-associations-with-references-or-repositories-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) instead of a direct object reference. Entities and aggregates should be consistency boundaries, not necessarily entire incarnations of concepts they represent. Also, take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=139) to go in-depth on this topic.

Comment: eulerfx, thank you veru much for your hint. It really does make sense. Now I'm totally revising the sceleton of my architecture.

Answer (score 0):

First, lazy loading is an antipattern in DDD, you need it if and only if entities provide access to more data than required to keep their invariants. To address this, you could use [shared identifiers](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/shared_identifiers.html) instead.

To decouple domain logic and persistency concerns you can use [observable entities](http://epic.tesio.it/doc/manual/observable_entities.html): the repository that provides the entity, keeps observing it so that, when proper domain events occurs, it can persist changes. However if you are coding in PHP, you have to code the Observer Pattern manually.