# How entities could be connected with each other inside the domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Let's assume there are two domain entities:

- **UserImages** with methods **addNewImage()**, **removeImage**(*$imageId*), **getImages**(*$from, $count*).
- **UserProfile** with fields **name**, **age**, **mainImageId**, etc.

Following functionality is desired inside the domain: when application layer calls **UserImages** -> **addNewImage()**, **UserProfile** -> **mainImageId** is set automatically in case it was empty.

So, what is the best way and best place to implement an in-domain over-entity business logic? Domain events with observing services, referencing special services from the entities, or somewhat else?

I create all the entities using a some kind of factory, i.e.

```
$userImages = Domain::userImages($userId); // getting an instance of UserImages
$newImageId = $userImages -> addNewImage();   // adding a new image
```

I also should mention that I will have a lot of logic like described above in my project.

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as specified in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472233/implementing-a-big-collection-entity-without-loading-data-into-memory), `UserImages` is not itself an entity. Instead, there is likely an entity called `UserImage` which refers to a user's image, singular. A `UserImageRepository` can then provide access to all images associated with a user, using pagination where necessary.

Now, the use case is:

> **When** a new user image is added, **if** a user's profile image is not set,
>   **set** it to the added image.

The term **when** indicates a [domain event](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/). In this case, the event is `UserImageAdded`. The bold **if** and the subsequent **set** represent the desired behavior in response to the event.

To implement this use case, an event must be published when a user image is added and a handler implementing the desired behavior must be subscribed to this event. This linked domain events article provides a sample implementation in C#, however the concept can be easily ported to PHP. Overall, the required components are:

- An **application service** which handles the adding of user images. This service will publish the event.
- A domain **event publisher** which is called by the application service and allows decoupling of publishers from subscribers.
- A domain **event handler** which handles the `UserImageAdded` event and invokes the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

User sounds like Aggregate for me (it's difficult to give you an opinion without context :) ), but it can solve your problem.

If Profil and Images are differents bounded context, may be you can use Domain events (it's helpful for cross bounded context communication)

Comment: Yes, I see **UserImages** and **UserProfile** as different context as the most time I don't need all the User's functions. Additionally, for some reason (NoSQL storage), I need a lot of cross-boundary connections inside the domain to implement profile search with the help of the domain itself and so on.

Comment: Like I sayed you can use Domain event, when you add an Image you publish an event... if you need an in real time notification.